# what is the proper way to structure this Text rendering in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a data object variable which outputs an array of names as expected via my VS Code console with the following line of code:

```
data.Subjects.map((x) => x.Name)
```

I'm trying to render Text components with the Name values like this:

```
data.Subjects.map((x) => {
    <Text>{x.Name}</Text>
});
```

However, the code above returns the following error in my Android emulator:

> "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a Text
>   component."

Any idea what the issue might be here or how I should update my code?

--UPDATE--

Ok here's a stripped down version of the render() method where the same error still occurs:

```
  render(){
    let data = ['test1','test2'];
    return (
      <>
        <View>
          data.map((x) => {
            <Text>x</Text>
          });
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
```

Comment: put your code inside a <div> or any tag.

Comment: @AspirinWang the code that I provided above is nested within a View component in my RN app

Comment: can you provide the whole code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Note: this does not mean just copy/paste your entire component here. Show just enough to illustrate what you are trying to do, including the relevant variable declarations.

Comment: ok - added MRE under "UPDATE" section in my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
render(){
  let data = ['test1','test2'];
  return (
    <View>
      {data.map((x) => (
        <Text>{x}</Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Basically your `data.map` is interpreted as text if you don't sorround it with brakets.

Also @ktad was right, you need to change your map like this:

```
data.map((x) => (
  <Text>{x}</Text>
))
```

or this:

```
data.map((x) => <Text>{x}</Text>)
```

or this:

```
data.map((x) => {
  return <Text>{x}</Text>
})
```

otherwise nothing is returned

Comment: this is the fix thanks!  the "x" in the Text component above just needs curly braces around it

Answer (score -1):

Try to use parentheses instead of curly braces

```
data.Subjects.map((x) => (
  <Text>{x.Name}</Text>
));
```

Comment: I tried that per your suggestion but the error still occurs